# MIPS: counting unique words in a plain text file and finding their Frequency

Tags: mips

first time ask question here. I am very frustrated by a homework assignment for MIPS. The assignment states: The input will be a plain text file, the output will be another file containing a list of words with their frequencies. The output file present two columns, the left column will be a word, the right column will be the number of frequency in the input file. For example, the output file could be look like this:

have: 2
  they: 3 
  is: 4
  i: 5

We are suppose to code this using MIPS Assembly. I do not understand how should I approach this kind of problem. I was thinking first read all the characters in the old file into a array in memory, and try to figure out a way to construct a second array contain all unique words and their frequencies.

So far, I can only be able to read the original file into an array. 
.data
    chars: .space 1024
    fin: .ascii "chill.txt"         # file name to read from
    uniqueWord: .space 1024

.text
main:

```
   Open a file 

li $v0, 13      # syscall for open file
la $a0, fin     # output file name
li $a1, 0       # open for read
li $a2, 0   
syscall
move $s6, $v0       # save the file descriptor

   read from the file that just opened

li $v0, 14      # syscall for read from file
move $a0, $s6       # file descriptoer
la $a1, chars       
li $a2, 1024
syscall

I try to use these to find the beginning and the ending or a word. 
add   $t4, $zero, $zero     # I = 0
add   $t0, $zero, $zero     # TOTAL = 0
add   $t1, $zero, 44        # ENDPOINT = ',' 
add   $t2, $zero, 32        # ENDPOINT = ' ' 
addi  $t3, $zero, 46        # ENDPOINT = '.'



loop:
lb    $t5, chars($t4)       # for c in chars
beq   $t5, $zero, endloop   #
beq   $t5, $t3,uniqueWord      # if c == '.'  go to uniqueWord 
beq   $t5, $t1,uniqueWord   # if c == ','  go to endloop
beq   $t5, $t2, uniqueWord  # if c == ' '  go to endloop
addi  $t4, $t4, 1           # i += 1       increment index
addi  $t0, $t0, 1           # total += 1     
j loop
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could give me direction on this assignment. Thanks a million times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With all complex assignments like this you should first write and debug a simple solution in C, then do a hand translation into assembly. You can develop a working solution quickly in C. Then all you need to do is verify that you have correctly translated it into assembly and debug any bugs you may have introduced in the assembly.

It is too complicated to think about the solution to a problem and think about the implementation of that solution in assembler at the same time. You will just get bogged down in details and get lost.  This is how I write stuff in assembly in my day job.

The simplest way to solve this would be to have an array containing all the words that have been seen so far, and a separate array with use-count for each word, so that the use-count for WORDS[0] is kept in COUNTS[0]. Then:

- when you read in a new word:
- compare it to each of the words in the array
- if it matches a word then increment the use-count for that word
- if you reach the end of the array without a match:

  - add the current word to the end of the array
  - increment the array length. If the array length exceeds the space you initially allocated for the array, give up and exit with an error

This is just a simple suggestion that won't be too hard to translate into assembler.  There are obviously many faster algorithms for this problem, such as trees and hash tables.

Comment: I tried to write in Java and translate over, but I am also stuck on how to write this problem in Java. :(   Thank you very much for your help